# connecting to wifi with password containing quotation mark

Tags: command-line, wifi, quoting, password

i'm trying to configure my debian from terminal using iwconfig command.
my wifi password contains quotation mark and iwconfig needs quotes around password like below:

`iwconfig wlan0 key "password"`

how can i use my password using iwconfig command, let's say that my pass is:

`123"abc`

Answer (score 2):

Need to surround in single quotes.

```
iwconfig wlan0 key 'abc"123'
```

Comment: i've already tried that and had following error:

Comment: Can't see the error, could you update your original question to feature the error details ?

Comment: `Error for wireless request "Set encode" (8B2A) : invalid argument "123"abc".`

Comment: @MarcinMarczyk Is this a WEP key or a WPA passphrase? I'm not sure that iwconfig supports the latter - see for example http://superuser.com/a/353818